# jQuery - Select element inside tinyMCE WYSIWYG

Tags: jquery, tinymce, tinymce-4

I have a site with some WYSIWYG-fields (using TinyMCE with Wordpress & Advanced Custom Fields). I want to select and manipulate some elements inside these fields (add a background image) but I'm not sure how to do that.

How can I reach inside TinyMCE's iFrame and modify elements?
How can I make sure all WYSIWYG-fields are properly loaded before I select them?

I'm looking at TinyMCE 4 API, and I still have no clue.

Comment: To get the HTML elements inside the TinyMCE editor use `tinymce.activeEditor.getContent({format: 'html'})`.

Comment: I don't want the content inside the editor, I want the body with ID "tinymce". That is located inside each iframe which make up each editor.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `init_instance_callback` function to set the iframe properties.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @WesFoster How is this a critique or a request for clarification? It is an answer, albeit a short one.

Comment: init_instance_callback: function (editor) {
  $('#' + editor.id + '_ifr').addClass('chatFrame');
}

Answer (score 0):

> How can I reach inside TinyMCE's iFrame and modify elements?

You can access the `Iframe` object using this.

```
tinymce.activeEditor.contentAreaContainer.childNodes[0];
```

You can access the `Iframes` `document` by using this.

```
tinymce.activeEditor.contentAreaContainer.childNodes[0].contentWindow.document;
```

> How can I make sure all WYSIWYG-fields are properly loaded before I select them?

To know when tinymce has been fully initialized, attach the `on init` event to the initialization of the editor.

```
tinymce.init({
    .....    
    setup: function(editor){
         //fired when tinymce is loaded
         editor.on('init', function(e){                
            //All Loaded 
         });                          
    }
});
```