# Select elements inside TinyMCE editor with jQuery

Tags: jquery, tinymce

I've tried many ways, but no lucky to accomplish to select elements inside TinyMCE with jQuery. I need to select like:

```
$("div",editor).css("border","1px solid red");
$("iframe div").css("border","1px solid red");
```

Does it possible? How?

Comment: You should check this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451208/access-iframe-elements-in-javascript

Comment: This will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32697711/jquery-select-element-inside-tinymce-wysiwyg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to select elements inside TinyMCE editor with jQuery you need to include the tinymce jquery library then you can get a dom element with:

```
$('#mytextarea').tinymce().$('body div')
```

Code example.  Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/4ug8nkqv/)

```js
tinymce.init({
    selector: '#mytextarea'
});

$('button').on('click', function(e) {
    $('#mytextarea').tinymce().$('body div').css("border","1px solid red");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/tinymce/tinymce-dist/master/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/tinymce/tinymce-dist/master/jquery.tinymce.min.js"></script>

<button>Click Me</button>
<textarea id="mytextarea">Hello, World!<div>hello word in div</div></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

iframes are protected; you can not access elements within it using JavaScript outside of it. I too found this out the hard way.

Instead, check out the TinyMCE API Reference. https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/api/

For example, you can use the function `tinymce.dom.DomQuery()` to access the elements in the editor:

```
tinymce.dom.DomQuery('div').css("border", "1px solid red");
```

EDIT: You can access iframes if they are from the same domain [Access iframe elements in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451208/access-iframe-elements-in-javascript). But I believe the DomQuery function is a lot quicker and easier